# Creating an ad set with Facebook Ads Management API

Tags: facebook, powershell

I am trying to create an ad set with the Facebook Ads Management API in Powershell.

The Access Token is current and has all rights in the "Events, Groups & Pages" section.

```
$parameters = @{
    name = "My ad set"
    optimization_goal = "POST_ENGAGEMENT"
    billing_event = "IMPRESSIONS"
    daily_budget = 5
    status = "PAUSED"
    campaign_id = "6052203335005"
    is_autobid = "true"
    start_time = "2016-08-24T11:59:09+02:00"
    end_time = "2016-08-25T11:59:09+02:00"
    targeting = '{"geo_locations":{"countries":["US"]}}'
    access_token = abc
}

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_12345678/adsets" -Body $parameters -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

I keep on getting an 400 error without further specification of what might be wrong.

```
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.Net.WebException: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (400) Ungültige Anforderung.
                       bei Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
                       bei Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          : System.Net.HttpWebRequest
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : bei Send-Command, C:\Users\...\Desktop\FacebookAdManagement.ps1: Zeile 31
                    bei Create-AdSet, C:\Users\...\Desktop\FacebookAdManagement.ps1: Zeile 65
                    bei <ScriptBlock>, <Keine Datei>: Zeile 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

I have tried:
- without contenttype specification
- removing a parameter, e.g. the billing_event, then I get a more descriptive "billing_event" missing error
- not passing the access token, then I get a more descriptive "you need an access token" error

How to find the culprit? And more importantly: how to fix it?

Thanks!

Sandro

Comment: The text of the response body should contain an exception, usually - are you able to see what that is?

Comment: I have tried this on a different machine now (to get you your answer before getting back home tonight). There I did indeed see a more useful response. Turns out that the daily_budget was set too low, because it is actually set in cents, not Euros/Dollars. Increasing it to a more appropriate amount solved the issue immediately.

Both machines are Win 10, the one it works on is PS version 5.0.10586.494 the other one I'd have to look up at home. What could cause this different behaviour? There must be a subtle difference in the code I use here and I used at home...

Comment: I can't think of any changes between v2.6 and v2.7 related to budgets, but that might be relevant, check which API version you're using in each case - daily budget is also dependent on what you're advertising / the optimization goal of the ad which may be relevant

Comment: I have used the very same script at home now and in that ISE, I do either not get the same error or don't get the same access to it. If anyone can chime in on why that might be, please do. Thanks Igy :-)